# Put in Symfony2 application production environment on a server

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3, symfony-2.7

HeI have created a Symfony2 application in development environment on the local server and when I finished it I uploaded it to a server. On the server it appears correctly, but it does not detect the .js and .css files. I guess the problem comes from the Assetic that I used in the development environment. I have seen that in the development environment you had to run `php app / console asetic: dump --env = prod --no-debug`, but in my free hosting I can not run command lines.

My configuration file config. yml is as follows:

```
  # Assetic Configuration
assetic:
 debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
 use_controller: false
 bundles:        [ ]
 #java: /usr/bin/java
 filters:
    cssrewrite: ~
    #closure:
    #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar"
    #yui_css:
    #    jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"
```

This is the first time I have deployed a project of this type, so I do not know very well how to do it. Could you tell me what steps I must take to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

I have this in my layout:

```
<link href="{{ asset('bundles/school/css/estilo.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="{{ asset('bundles/backend/js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="{{ asset('bundles/school/js/e-calendar-master/css/jquery.e-calendar.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

...//some more
```

And running `app/console asetic:dump --env=prod` I only get this:

```
Dumping all prod assets.
Debug mode is off.
```

Looking for information I have seen something like this:

```
{% stylesheets

  'bundles/school/css/estilo.css'
  'bundles/backend/js/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.css'
  'bundles/school/js/e-calendar-master/css/jquery.e-calendar.css'
%}
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

With this I create a .css file inside the web/css folder

Can I solve my problem with some of that?

Answer (score 0):

First need to add in config.yml file bundle list into bundles param where you need to include assetic:

```
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ AppBundle, DesignBundle ],
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
```

Then you need to execute the commands to generate the files:

```
bin/console assets:install
bin/console assetic:dump --env=prod
```

UPDATE #2:

Try with something like this in twig template:

```
{% stylesheets filter='cssrewrite'
    'bundles/app/public/css/main.css'
    {# or #}
    '@AppBundle/Resources/public/css/main.css'
%}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

and for js

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {% javascripts
        'bundles/app/public/js/main.js'
        {# or #}
        '@AppBundle/Resources/public/js/main.js'
    %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock javascripts %}
```

Comment: Hello @mlivan, he performed what you say, adding the bundles I have in my project, since I had not created the AppBundle, and then I cleaned the cache and executed the other instructions. I have obtained: `Dumping all prod assets. Debug mode is off.` Is there any way to check that everything is fine or can I just check it when uploading the project back to the server?

Comment: when start those command you will see the list of js file how system add into the web folder. All assets is into web/assets folder by default

Comment: you mean for example to this? `Installing assets for School\SchoolBundle into web/bundles/school`. This comes with `assets:install` but with `assetic:dump` I only get what I indicated before. I do not have any web/assets folder

Comment: I have seen there something to use in the template `{% stylesheets%} 'to include the stylesheets used. Do I have to do any of that? I still have it in the form `<link href="{{ asset('bundles/school/css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`